# Huge differences in performance between Order By ASC vs DESC

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am recording a huge difference between ORDER BY ASC and DESC in CosmosDB SQL API. ASC is almost 200x less expensive in RUs than DESC.

Here is output from my testing tool:

```
INFO ------------------- QUERY -----------------

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM root
WHERE
    root.projectId = '783af8f2-8e2f-0083-5d86-2f60f34e11b4'
        AND NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.translatedLanguages, '0d42a87f-4d68-417b-99a9-a228cb63edce')
ORDER BY root._srtDue DESC


INFO ------------------- ROUND 1 -----------------
INFO Request Charge: 2532.53
INFO Count: 100
INFO Metrics: {
  "TotalTime": "00:00:01.7036800",
  "RetrievedDocumentCount": 38238,
  "RetrievedDocumentSize": 236459696,
  "OutputDocumentCount": 100,
  "IndexHitRatio": 0.0,
  "QueryPreparationTimes": {
    "CompileTime": "00:00:00.0001900",
    "LogicalPlanBuildTime": "00:00:00.0000700",
    "PhysicalPlanBuildTime": "00:00:00.0000600",
    "QueryOptimizationTime": "00:00:00.0000100"
  },
  "QueryEngineTimes": {
    "IndexLookupTime": "00:00:00.0298500",
    "DocumentLoadTime": "00:00:01.4093599",
    "WriteOutputTime": "00:00:00.0001300",
    "RuntimeExecutionTimes": {
      "TotalTime": "00:00:00.2636001",
      "SystemFunctionExecutionTime": "00:00:00.0132800",
      "UserDefinedFunctionExecutionTime": "00:00:00"
    }
  },
  "Retries": 0
}
```

vs

```
INFO ------------------- QUERY -----------------

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM root
WHERE
    root.projectId = '783af8f2-8e2f-0083-5d86-2f60f34e11b4'
        AND NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.translatedLanguages, '0d42a87f-4d68-417b-99a9-a228cb63edce')
ORDER BY root._srtDue ASC


INFO ------------------- ROUND 1 -----------------
INFO Request Charge: 14.22
INFO Count: 100
INFO Metrics: {
  "TotalTime": "00:00:00.0047500",
  "RetrievedDocumentCount": 131,
  "RetrievedDocumentSize": 187130,
  "OutputDocumentCount": 100,
  "IndexHitRatio": 0.75572519083969469,
  "QueryPreparationTimes": {
    "CompileTime": "00:00:00.0001300",
    "LogicalPlanBuildTime": "00:00:00.0000700",
    "PhysicalPlanBuildTime": "00:00:00.0000600",
    "QueryOptimizationTime": "00:00:00.0000100"
  },
  "QueryEngineTimes": {
    "IndexLookupTime": "00:00:00.0010400",
    "DocumentLoadTime": "00:00:00.0020299",
    "WriteOutputTime": "00:00:00.0002200",
    "RuntimeExecutionTimes": {
      "TotalTime": "00:00:00.0008301",
      "SystemFunctionExecutionTime": "00:00:00.0000500",
      "UserDefinedFunctionExecutionTime": "00:00:00"
    }
  },
  "Retries": 0
}
```

I have not found how exactly is IndexHitRatio computed and how is Cosmos DB execution planned, but it looks to me, that in this particular case, it runs predicates against documents in specified order direction, and documents fulfilling those predicates are at the end of that sorting order so it has to read lots of documents, 38K, to get those TOP 100 output documents.

We believe we have all properly indexed:

```
path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
...
"path": "/translatedLanguages/[]/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
```

Unfortunately, this performance is not acceptable for our use case and if we don't solve it somehow we would be forced to change database engine.

Is there a way to tweak this execution plan somehow to improve performance?

Comment: This most likely is happening because the index is not being used for the query. From the snippet, you have defined indexes on the all the paths, but maybe you have columns names that are creating index collisions. Try creating separate index for only the `_srtDue` column.

Comment: Manish, how is index collision possible? Same column names?

Comment: I am from the Cosmos DB Engineering Team. Could you please email the database account name, database name, collection name and ActivityIds of the two queries to krishs at microsoft dot com?